# Excel - Macro, Copy to new Workbook not working for multiple of 8 Rows

Tags: excel, csv, macros, vba

I was trying to copy a particular number of rows from .xlsm format workbook to a .csv file using macro code. The code works fine if I have to copy 7 rows. Here's the screenshot of 7 rows being copied into the .csv file. 
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9v5q.png)

The problem arises when I try to copy rows in the multiples of 8. The 8 rows are copied infinitely till the end of the worksheet like so:
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFgAy.png)

Here is the code I'm using. (The code remains the same for 7 or 8 rows)

```
    For I = Col1 To Last_col - 1                
            ws.Range(Cells(1, I), Cells(LastRow, I)).Copy Destination:=wsNew.Columns(k1)
            k1 = k1 + 1
       Next I
```

* Here k1 is initialised as Long with value 1 and the `LastRow` variable takes on the value of 7 (or 8). Note that Col1 is the first column to be copied.

I am new to Excel macros and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may need to provide more code to see how the indices/parameters (e.g. `LastRow`, `I` and `k1`) evolve.

Comment: @FDavidov I have edited the code.

Comment: Are you just trying to copy one area from one worksheet to another?  If so, you could just do `ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, Col1), ws.Cells(LastRow, Last_col - 1)).Copy wsNew.Range("A1")`, without the need for a loop.

Comment: @YowE3K That is right and I eventually got the code to run using a similar approach. But I can't figure out why that code is not running for LastRow = 8 (or it's multiples).

Comment: You were copying to a whole column - it probably would do the same for any number of rows that evenly divides into the total number of rows in the worksheet (i.e. all the factors of 1048576 or 65536 depending on what version of Excel).

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks! You were right. It happens for any rows that evenly divide the total number of rows. But I am wondering if it will be possible to somehow edit the code `ws.Range(Cells(1, I), Cells(LastRow, I)).Copy Destination:=wsNew.Columns(k1)` within the loop itself such that the  error can be rectified. Please post your previous comment as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel attempts to fill the entire destination range with your copied range.

Where the number of rows in the source **is not** a factor of the destination rows, it determines that it isn't possible to do so evenly and just copies the source once.

Where the number of rows in the source **is** a factor of the destination rows, Excel just repeats the source over and over to fill the entire destination area.

In your case, 7 is not a factor of 1048576 so only one copy is made.  8 is a factor of 1048576 so 131072 copies are made.  The same "duplication" will occur with a source range of 1 row, 2 rows, 4 rows, 16 rows, 32 rows, etc.

Your code could be rewritten as:

```
For I = Col1 To Last_col - 1                
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, I), ws.Cells(LastRow, I)).Copy Destination:=wsNew.Range(wsNew.Cells(1, k1), wsNew.Cells(LastRow, k1))
    k1 = k1 + 1
Next I
```

Or you could avoid the loop and just use:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, Col1), ws.Cells(LastRow, Last_col - 1)).Copy wsNew.Range("A1")
```